# db2 script: how to comment if I want to run the whole script at once with multiple statements?

Tags: db2

I currently have lots of sql statements in db2 and I'm putting it in a script and using Query Tool to run all the commands after highlighting all my sql statements.

My comments are like so:

/*
 comments
*/
However, Query Tool complains of the following:

SQL0198N  The statement string of the PREPARE or EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement is blank or empty.  SQLSTATE=42617

I've tried using dash dash.  Same issue.  I remember taking a mysql class before and I was able to submit full scripts for the instructor to grade.

someone else is also having the same issue:
http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1118891-How-do-i-put-comment-in-DB2-UDB-7-2

Comment: Can you try to run the script with "--" comments with "db2 -tvf script.sql"? I wondering if it's something to do with Query Tool.

Comment: I don't understand.  How do I run the script as you suggest?  I run the script inside Query tool by selecting everything and hit the green arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Put your SQL statements inside a file called script.sql

```
 -- sample comment
 -- create nation table

 CREATE TABLE "TPCD    "."NATION"  (
      "N_NATIONKEY" INTEGER NOT NULL , 
      "N_NAME" CHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
      "N_REGIONKEY" INTEGER NOT NULL , 
      "N_COMMENT" VARCHAR(152) NOT NULL );
```

Then log into your instance user from command line:

```
 su - db2inst1
```

And run your script.sql

```
 db2 -tvf script.sql
```

Please try and see if it works.